# How to join YEARS from 2 tables with different format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a custom view in excel for a pivot,  I cant join the YEARSF because the tb1 format is 2016-17 and tb2 is 2016/17, how can i join these, see code below... what is the appropriate way of doing this

```
TB1.YEARF = TB2.YEARF
```

Seems to be the issue

```
     SELECT TB1.YEARF, 
TB1.MC,
TB1.CATEG, 
TB1.ID, 
TB1.TY, 
TB1.CAT, 
TB1.LOC, 
TB2.HD0_NAME,
TB2.HD1_NAME, 
TB2.HD2_NAME, 
TB2.HD3_NAME, 
TB2.HD4_NAME
FROM DB.TB2 TB2, DB.TB1 TB1
WHERE TB2.CAT = TB1.CAT AND TB2.LOC = TB1.LOC AND TB1.TY = TB2.TY AND TB1.YEARF = TB2.YEARF AND TB1.ID = TB2.ID
```

Comment: which db you are using  ..?? .  remove the tag for the others

Comment: Format the date to a standard format and then join the dates.

Comment: Your question's tags mention both [mysql] and [oracle]. Presumably your query addresses one, but not both, those table server systems.  Which one? The answer to your question is different in the two different cases.

Comment: You can change the format on the fly in your query. You don't need to change it on the database table.

Comment: using oracle to do this

Comment: are these defined as strings (varchar) in the database?  If so, just strip - and / as needed in the query

Comment: WHAT IF TB1.YEARF is 2000-01 and TB2 is 2000, and would need tb2 to be 2000-01?  VARCHAR

Comment: @FLMD: How can TB2 be '2000'? You said the format is 'YYYY/MM'.

Comment: I recommend you change one of the tables' values, so the formats match. Then have indexes on the columns to have your joins fast. (You can write a trigger to convert from one format to the other even, to make sure that after your update only well-formatted entries get written.)

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag, as the OP said it's Oracle. I also removed the inappropriate Excel tag and the superfluous Select tag.

Comment: Why are you using pre-1992 joins? Are you working on such an old system? If not, switch to proper ANSI joins.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that both [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) have `REPLACE()` functions.

If you change the part of your query that reads

```
 AND TB1.YEARF = TB2.YEARF AND
```

to

```
 AND TB1.YEARF = REPLACE(TB2.YEARF, '/', '-') AND
```

you may be able to join these tables.  It's not going to be fast.

In general, to do this kind of inexact matching, you have to

1. figure out the rules for matching. For example, if you want `abcd/ef` to match `abcd-ef` then you can use what I wrote above.  If you want `abcd/ef` to match `abcd`, that's a different rule.
2. Write a SQL expression to implement your rules.

But, you know, step 1 must come before step 2.

If all you care about is matching the `abcd` parts of `abcd/ef` and `abcd-ef` you can write a rule for that.

```
 AND SUBSTR(TB1.YEARF, 1, 4) = SUBSTR(TB2.YEARF, 1, 4) AND
```

Comment: WHAT IF TB1.YEARF is 2000-01 and TB2 is 2000, and would need tb2 to be 2000-01?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Format(TB1.YEARF, "yyyy-dd") = Format(TB2.YEARF, "yyyy-dd")
```

Comment: WHAT IF TB1.YEARF is 2000-01 and TB2 is 2000, and would need tb2 to be 2000-01?

Comment: you have to make sure if take all the cases into considerations. convert both of column to same format and then use in join condition

Comment: @FLMD it sounds like you have some bad data then. If you know that all records with the value of 2000 should actually be 2000-01, then why hasn't that value been changed? Linking can never assume that a Year value SHOULD contain a month but doesn't. The data has to be there